# Highest Goal Difference to be knocked out of the World Cup at the Group Stage

Tags: football, world-cup

During the final games of the group stages at the Qatar 2022 World Cup, for 3 brief minutes in Group E, both Spain and Germany were in line to be knocked out of the World Cup.

During those 3 minutes, with the scores being Costa Rica 2-1 Germany; Japan 2-1 Spain - the "As it stands" Group E table looked like this:

| Group E | P | W | D | L | GD | Pts |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Japan | 3 | 2 | 0 | 1 | +1 | 6 |
| Costa Rica | 3 | 2 | 0 | 1 | -5 | 6 |
| Spain | 3 | 1 | 1 | 1 | +6 | 4 |
| Germany | 3 | 0 | 1 | 2 | -2 | 1 |

This would have been remarkable in of itself, but even more so that Spain had a +6 goal difference, mostly coming from their 7-0 demolition of Costa Rica in the opening round.

What is the highest Goal Difference a team has had and also been knocked out of the World Cup at the group stages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That would be [Hungary at the 1982 World Cup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1982_FIFA_World_Cup_Group_3). They beat El Salvador 10-1 in their first match - the largest ever margin of victory at a World Cup - but then lost 4-1 to Argentina and drew 1-1 with Belgium, which meant they finished 3rd in the group with a goal difference of +6.